# sql question , calculate salary + commission annually + change headings

Tags: sql, oracle

Question :retrieve the name and total annual earnings, i.e. salary plus commission, of all employees who are paid a commission; the headings of the resulting table column should be titled EMP NAME and ANNUAL EARNINGS respectively.

My answer

SELECT ename, sal * 12 + nvl(comm, 0)
FROM emp;

Can someone explain to me how to change the column name to ANNUAL EARNINGS ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbxd0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use aliases, so try this:

```
SELECT 
ename AS "EMP NAME", 
sal * 12 + nvl(comm, 0) AS "ANNUAL EARNINGS"
FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias to change how an expression is projected, try the below examples

```
Select 1 “white SPACE alias”
, 2 any_old_alias
, 3 as optional_as
From dual;
```

Note that you might be missing they requirement to filter “all employees who are paid a commission”